# Fetch Order Details Of A Particular Sellers From Flipkart To Our Website

Tags: web, flipkart-api

**Hi Developer,**

I am working on a website where I want to fetch all my client Flipkart seller's order details to my client website from where they can manage their order, what will be the possible way to integrate it, Will Flipkart allow me to see my Client order details on the website

**Thanks!**

Comment: search in google flipkart api's

Comment: https://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_prod_ref.html

Comment: https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

using this you will get orders

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "filter": {
                "orderDate": {
            "fromDate": "2022-02-01T00:00:01.19800Z",
            "toDate": "2022-02-03T20:43:30.19800Z"
        }
    }
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer $token',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```